# Roll up data from a column into 1 comma delineated cell in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table like this:

```
Name  | Start Time
item1 | 4:00PM
item1 | 6:00PM
item2 | 3:00PM
```

How can I roll up the start time column so the end result would be

```
Name  | Start Time
item1 | 4:00PM,6:00PM
item2 | 3:00PM
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee40f/2

Comment: @TMNT2014 Thanks amazing, works perfectly!  Thanks!  (Put it as the answer if you want the points)